# How to create keycloak client role programmatically and assign to user

Tags: java, keycloak

I want to create keycloak client role programmatically and assign to user created dynamically. Below is my code for creating user

```
UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setEmail("xxxxx@xxx.com");
user.setUsername("xxxx");
user.setFirstName("xxx");
user.setLastName("m");
user.setEnabled(true);
Response response = kc.realm("YYYYY").users().create(user);
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution to your request (not very beautiful, but it works):

```
// Get keycloak client
Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost:8080/auth",
                "master", "admin", "admin", "admin-cli");

// Create the role
RoleRepresentation clientRoleRepresentation = new RoleRepresentation();
clientRoleRepresentation.setName("client_role");
clientRoleRepresentation.setClientRole(true);
kc.realm("RealmID").clients().findByClientId("ClientID").forEach(clientRepresentation ->
    kc.realm("RealmID").clients().get(clientRepresentation.getId()).roles().create(clientRoleRepresentation)
);

// Create the user
UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setUsername("test");
user.setEnabled(true);
Response response = kc.realm("RealmID").users().create(user);
String userId = getCreatedId(response);

// Assign role to the user
kc.realm("RealmID").clients().findByClientId("ClientID").forEach(clientRepresentation -> {
    RoleRepresentation savedRoleRepresentation = kc.realm("RealmID").clients()
            .get(clientRepresentation.getId()).roles().get("client_role").toRepresentation();
    kc.realm("RealmID").users().get(userId).roles().clientLevel(clientRepresentation.getId())
            .add(asList(savedRoleRepresentation));
});

// Update credentials to make sure, that the user can log in
UserResource userResource = kc.realm("RealmID").users().get(userId);
userResource.resetPassword(credential);
```

With the help method:

```
private String getCreatedId(Response response) {
    URI location = response.getLocation();
    if (!response.getStatusInfo().equals(Response.Status.CREATED)) {
        Response.StatusType statusInfo = response.getStatusInfo();
        throw new WebApplicationException("Create method returned status " +
                statusInfo.getReasonPhrase() + " (Code: " + statusInfo.getStatusCode() + "); expected status: Created (201)", response);
    }
    if (location == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String path = location.getPath();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}
```

Comment: it actually works.But on my 2 angular apps, Restricted client role can log in.

Comment: I guess that's because you haven't properly configured this client role within your angular apps. Check [this link](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html) for more information.

Comment: i have configured correctly check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226287/keycloak-per-app-role-mapping

Comment: At keycloak version 4.0.0.Final `org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.UsersResource` doesn't contain resetPassword() method. What else can you suggest to use

Comment: dont't know if it's ok to ask on such an old post but
```java
 private void createClientRole(String clientRole, Keycloak kc) {
  RoleRepresentation clientRoleRepresentation = new RoleRepresentation();
  clientRoleRepresentation.setName(clientRole);
  clientRoleRepresentation.setClientRole(true);
  kc.realm(this.realm).clients().findByClientId(clientId).forEach(clientRepresentation ->
   kc.realm(this.realm).clients().get(clientRepresentation.getId()).roles().create(clientRoleRepresentation)
  );
 }
```

getting a http 409 response, dont know how to fix :(

Comment: You might be able to use org.keycloak.admin.client.CreatedResponseUtil#getCreatedId instead of the private help method mentioned in the answer

Comment: @R.Polito i have the same problem right know. did you fix it?